# Как загрузить zip?

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip

Я использую этот код для загрузки, сохранения и показа изображения. Это работает. Но я хочу загрузить zip файл с моим изображением, распаковать. Далее сохранить и показать изображение. Как мне это сделать?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.png" ];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button addTarget:self
            action:@selector(btnClicked:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
_button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[_button setBackgroundImage: image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:_button];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.png"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];


NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

- (IBAction)playAction:(id)sender {
if(_downloadTask == nil){

    _url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/ios-png-6.png"];
_downloadTask = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:_url];
    [_downloadTask resume];

}

else

[_downloadTask resume];
}
```

Comment: найти на гитхабе библиотеку, которая распаковывет зип

Comment: А разве http запросы сами не архивируют данные? Может не так хорошо как библиотека, зато на лету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [ZipZap](https://github.com/pixelglow/ZipZap), [Objective-Zip](https://github.com/gianlucabertani/Objective-Zip) или другую похожую библиотеку.

Вот [готовая инструкция](https://habrahabr.ru/post/196602/) на русском